# how to resolve dotNet framework 3.5 installation error 0x80080005?

Tags: .net-framework-version

.Net framework installation error

I get following error when I try to install .Net framework 3.5.

Server Execution Failed

Error Code: 0x80080005[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7kKv.jpg)

Could someone plese help me on this error ?

Answer (score 0):

More information would be needed to provide a more accurate answer, such as why are you trying to install .NET Framework 3.5, and where from.

These steps from [winchatsupport](https://www.winchatsupport.com/error-code-0x80080005/#:%7E:text=Sometimes%20error%20code%200x80080005%20can,of%20your%20Windows%2010%20computer.) may solve your issue:

1. Control Panel > Programs and Features.
2. Turn Windows features on or off then check .NET framework 3.5. The pre-requisites should installed.
3. If it is not successful uninstall the KB’s related to .NET framework 3.5 and then re-install them.
4. Restart your computer if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have tried with the control panel option and I get the same below error    Server Execution Failed

Error Code: 0x80080005

Comment: Adding more details "Your device is missing important security and quality fixes.There were some problems installing updates, but we'll try again later. If you keep seeing this and want to search the web or contact support for information, this may help: (0x80080005)